# Delphi WriteComponent does not stream children or multiple components

Tags: delphi

I have been trying to stream the contents of a TTabSheet, but WriteComponent just streams the TTabSheet object, but not the controls on it.

To get around this I thought I could stream all the controls on the tabsheet, using the following code, but this only streams the first control.

```
procedure TfrmMain.SaveComponentToFile(Component: TComponent; const FileName: TFileName);
var
  FileStream : TFileStream;
  MemStream : TMemoryStream;
  i: integer;
begin
  MemStream := nil;

  if not Assigned(Component) then raise Exception.Create('Component is not assigned');

  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmCreate);
  try
    MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    //ShowMessage(IntToStr(TTabSheet(Component).ControlCount));
    for i := 0 to TTabSheet(Component).ControlCount - 1 do begin
      Memstream.WriteComponent(TTabSheet(Component).Controls[i]);
    end;
    MemStream.Position := 0;
    ObjectBinaryToText(MemStream, FileStream);
  finally
    MemStream.Free;
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The commented out ShowMessage does show the correct number of controls on the tabsheet, so why is the loop not streaming all 35 components?

Comment: WriteComponent works by ownership, so it basically uses the Components property of the tabsheet and works through the hierarchy from there. 

Controls is the parent/child relationship, Components is the ownership relationship. The easiest solution would be if you could  make the tabsheet the owner of those components.

Comment: ObjectBinaryToText also reads such a hierarchy. It will start with the first object, and when that finished, it won't expect anything else in the stream.

Comment: To clarify my first comment: Typically the form owns the components, even if the tabsheet is their parent.

Comment: Thank you @GolezTrol, please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.